# Unexpected side effect with java streams reduce operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, side-effects

I'm observing a side effect on an underlying collection when calling 'reduce' on a Stream. This is so basic. I can't believe what I am seeing, but I can't find the error. Below is the code and the resulting output. Can anyone explain to me why one of the underlying collections of the Stream is mutating?

```
package top;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

        list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6));
        list3.addAll(Arrays.asList(7, 8, 9));

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
        System.out.println(list3);

        ArrayList<Integer> r1 = Stream.of(list1, list2, list3).reduce((l, r) -> {
            l.addAll(r);
            return l;
        }).orElse(new ArrayList<>());

        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println(list1);
        System.out.println(list2);
        System.out.println(list3);

        System.out.println("Result");
        System.out.println(r1);

    }
}

// Output
Before
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
After
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] // Why is this not [1,2,3]?
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
Result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Crap. I think I'm realizing that this is just the way it works in Java. Is that right? Really?

Comment: What do you think `l.addAll(r)` does? It **updates** the content of the `l` list. So why are you confused that the list is updated?

Comment: Yes, you are explicitly telling your code to do this: with `l.addAll(r); return l;` you tell to add everything to the left list and then return the left list. For each iteration, the left list is `list1`. Well, I think Brian's answer explains enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use another overload of `Stream.reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` which allows to seed accumulator, i.e.

```
ArrayList<Integer> r1 = Stream.of(list1, list2, list3)
   .reduce(new ArrayList<>(), (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;})
```

In your case you do not provide seed for accumulator so the first available value is used.

Answer (score 1):

[`TStream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) takes (possibly arbitrary?) pairs of elements and applies your accumulator to them. This is not what you want given that accumulator, since `ArrayList<>.addAll` mutates the list.

A solution is to create a new list in your accumulator and append the args to that, or use the `Stream.collect` function with either your own `Collector`, or `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)`

This also means that your `.orElse(new ArrayList<>())` isn't ever needed, because the identity will be returned in that case.

Note that technically your function is not [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity), so your list may not always end up in the same order if it doesn't run sequentially.

Comment: Using the other form will not negate the need for the reduction operation to be stateless. If the stream is executed in parallel mode, that single identify "value" is used independently by each thread, causing total havoc. You can't do that, so your suggested solution is flawed.

Comment: Ok, it should be correct now.

Comment: The function is associative in respect to the result, it’s just unpredictable which lists are affected by the side effects. It should be noted that if not a specific type of `List` is needed, `Collectors.toList()` is the way to go. And you answer start with a `TStream` which should be `Stream`, I guess…